# Core 2 Quad motherboard compatibility

Tags: cpu, motherboard, compatibility, processor-socket

Will a [BOXDP965LTCK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GS2QX0) motherboard work with a Core 2 Quad 1066 FSB (Q6600)? It's listed as Core 2 compatible but they only say Duo and Extreme, not Quad - will it work anyways?

Comment: That board is an Intel desktop motherboard. Intel has a link to the supported CPU's. See 
http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/dp965lt/sb/CS-026556.htm?wapkw=dp965lt
for which CPU are supported. If it is not in the list then it will not work.

Comment: What is wrong with this question?

Comment: @Hennes Thank you for that link. If you post that as an answer, I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That board is an Intel desktop motherboard. Intel has a link to the supported CPU's.

See http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/dp965lt/sb/CS-026556.htm?wapkw=dp965lt for which CPU's are supported.

If it is not in the list then it will not work.

If it is in the list and your BIOS version is too old then you want to update the BIOS **before** changing the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

According to Intel, the P965 chipset will not support the Q6600  [Intel P 965 Compatability](http://ark.intel.com/products/27730/Intel-82P965-Memory-Controller)

Comment: http://processormatch.intel.com/CompDB/SearchResult.aspx?Boardname=dp965lt This shows it as compatible. Are you sure?

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/products/27730/Intel-82P965-Memory-Controller As does this. I think you are mistaken.

Comment: For the record, Dave M's original answer claims it does not support it.